# How can I show a different contact form on a page depending which page linked through to that page? (Contact Form 7)

Tags: php, dynamic, wordpress, contact-form-7

I currently have four pages, each of which have a button containing a PHP get variable, which loads the "apply" page and fills out one of the fields using the variable:

Button:

```
[button color="accent-color" size="medium" url="/careers/apply?variable=variable_name" text="Button"]
```

"Apply" Page:

```
[contact-form-7 id="1467" title="Contact form 1"]
```

However, rather than just have one contact form for all of the four pages to use, I'd like to have 4 different contact forms, and for each form to be used depending on which of these 4 pages linked through to the "apply" page. Is there an easy way to do this? I'm looking to avoid having 4 separate apply pages for each contact form!

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Duney am not a PHP developer but i can advice you on a logic to use based on my ASP.NET encounters. You could assign a value to a variable and pass that value as a parameter through to your contact page. When you get to your contact page you could use a case statement or a conditioned statement to check this value then display appropriate messages based on the values(1,2,3 or 4).